# Find the average() of a count() in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate the average of a resultset from `count` function. I used this query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(AVG(purchase) AS NUMERIC (5,3))
FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as purchase 
     FROM transactions
     GROUP BY payer_id) X
```

but I get as result the value "1". I use Excel to verify this result and it is supposed to be 1,635264484.

I also wanted to return both the count() list and the average of this list so I rewrite my query like this:

```
SELECT 
    tr1.payer_id, count(*) AS purchase
FROM 
    transactions AS tr1
GROUP BY 
    payer_id 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'avg = ', AVG(X.purchase) 
FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as purchase
     FROM transactions tr2
     GROUP BY tr2.payer_id) X
```

Now, the query runs for a while and then the following error message is shown:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

The column `payer_id` is numeric(38,0).

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @konna-papag, what results do you have when you are running your first query and what results do you have when you are running your second query?

Comment: It seems like an integer division problem. What do you get if you try `SELECT count(*)*1.0 as purchase`?

Comment: assuming tr1.payer_id is an integer this will cause a problem when you later on union it with a field containing a string (avg =). I think this is where the error is coming from. You may also need to convert the second column to a fixed type (count gives you int, avg may give you float)

Comment: Cast integer count to numeric before calculating average: `AVG(CAST(purchase AS numeric(5,3)))`

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I get this error: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: @konna.papag, you chose precision 5 for `numeric(5,3)`. Apparently it is not enough. Look up the T-SQL `numeric` type.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I tried that and I have the same problem again. The average is 1 instead of 1,635264484. Can you help?

Comment: `avg( cast(purchase AS float)` is the answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `'avg ='` to numeric, which it tries due to your UNION, because your player_id is numeric.

If you cast payer_id to text, it should work:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(tr1.payer_id AS VARCHAR(255)), count(*) AS purchase
FROM 
    transactions AS tr1
GROUP BY 
    payer_id 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'avg = ', AVG(X.purchase) 
FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as purchase
     FROM transactions tr2
     GROUP BY tr2.payer_id) X
```

Comment: Hi @allan-s-hansen, very interesting ! Thanks.

Comment: Now I have the initial problem again, the average is 1 instead of 1,635264484. I also tried to change this: `SELECT 'avg = ', AVG(X.purchase)` to this: `SELECT 'avg = ', AVG(CAST(purchase AS numeric(5,3)))`  but the query runs for a second and then I get this message: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: Cast your count(*) to decimal or numeric. The first table in a union determines the data types.